# How to write an app that works in background ios

Tags: ios, xcode, background

I need to write small app that runs in ios background to check battery level and make some sound when battery level is 100% and 20%

what it the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the right way? What about what way have you tried? And doesn't the iPhone already notify us when we hit 20%?

Comment: I need to send a signal to audio jack for external device - when 20% or 100%. I want my app work in background mode checking the level of battery.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third-party library called [BatteryChart](https://github.com/nst/BatteryChart). You may check its source code to get some ideas. Personally, I'm not quite sure about the background task. Good luck.